# Rails Search with query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to filter jobs on the parameter passed onto the model, currently search works flawlessly without query passed into the model, but when I type query it doesn't return anything. How can I perform this query with query and criteria. 
**results << model.with_query(query).where(criteria)**. any idea would be really appreciated.

```
module Refinery
  class SearchEngine
    # How many results should we show per page
    RESULTS_LIMIT = 100

    # Perform search over the specified models

    def self.search(query, job_region, job_division, country, job_type, page = 1)
      results = []

      Refinery.searchable_models.each do |model|

      criteria = {:job_region => job_region,
                    :job_division => job_division,
                    :country => country,
                    :job_type => job_type

        }.select { |key, value| value.present? }


        if query.present?
          results << model.with_query(query).where(criteria)
        else
          results << model.limit(RESULTS_LIMIT).where(criteria)
        end

      end

      results.flatten[0..(RESULTS_LIMIT - 1)]
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: what is the expected content of "query"? Raw SQL? A hash of conditions?

Comment: Hash of conditions, if there is no query pass into model it returns what is expected, but with_query it doesn't work. I am using act_as_index gem to perform query search.

Comment: It may sounds stupid but try the other way: `model.where(criteria).with_query(query)` (where returns an ActiveRecord::Relation which is able to chain-scope, and maybe .with_query just returns an Array)

Comment: MrYoshiji, this is not stupid, this is magic :-). it is working now. really appreciated for your time. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the method `.with_query(qry)` returns an Array. You want to do chain-scoping, so you must use scopes that returns ActiveRecord::Relation objects.

```
model.with_query(query) 
# returns an Array

model.with_query(query).where(criteria) 
# calling .where on an Array object => NoMethodError

model.where(criteria) 
# returns an ActiveRecord::Relation

model.where(criteria).with_query(query) 
# calls the query on an AR::Relation object, which is doable
```

---

**Short version**: Change this:

```
results << model.with_query(query).where(criteria)
```

To this:

```
results << model.where(criteria).with_query(query)
```